# Issue using external-program on macOS 10.15

Tags: macos, common-lisp, sbcl, macos-catalina

While on my old machine running macOS 10.13 `external-program` works as expected, I am not able to use it anymore to communicate with an external process. I can start the process but as soon as I want to finish an input stream I get an

```
Couldn't write to #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "descriptor 8" {1002A51593}>:
  Broken pipe
```

error. I am using `SBCL` 1.5.9 on macOS 10.15. If I try the example from [Edi's book, p. 689](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484211779) the error occurs:

*foo.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main (void) {
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
     putchar(c);
     if (c == '\n')
       fflush(stdout);
     else
       putchar(c);
   }
return 0; }
```

Using [external-program](https://github.com/sellout/external-program).

Compile with `gcc -o foo foo.c` and than in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (external-program:start "~/Desktop/foo" nil
                                 :input :stream :output :stream)
#<SB-IMPL::PROCESS 1833 :RUNNING>
CL-USER> (defparameter *p* *)
*P*
CL-USER> (defparameter *in*
(external-program:process-input-stream *p*))
*IN*
CL-USER> (defparameter *out*
(external-program:process-output-stream *p*))
*OUT*
CL-USER> (format *in* "addressee~%")
NIL
CL-USER> (finish-output *in*)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:BROKEN-PIPE "~@<~?~@[: ~2I~_~A~]~:>" {1002A57043}>.
```

Does anyone know what has been changed with macOS 10.15. that disturbs the inter process communication?

**EDIT**

If I try running `foo` in a terminal it does behave as expected:

```
➜ ./foo
abcdefg
aabbccddeeffgg
```

Comment: Did you try running `foo` stand-alone in Terminal to see if it behaves as expected there?

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: I am sorry if this is too os-specific but I really think it is an issue. And I assume I am not the only one running CL on macOS. So a solution would be helpful for others too.

Comment: my guess: a security problem with sbcl (and some other implementations) and/or the external-program library under macOS 10.15. The example works for me in Clozure CL and LispWorks under macOS 10.15. macOS 10.15 is more strict about which programs are allowed to run external programs.

Comment: @RainerJoswig You are totally right. It just took me a while to find the right settings. Allowing `SBCL` to _control my computer_ did the trick.

Comment: @MartinBuchmann : thanks for finding it

Comment: Unfortunately, while the example above works now, I am still failing to send a binary stream to ffmpeg.

Comment: Which was indeed an issue with ffmpeg installed via macports and not a SBCL issue at all :-)